# Inline css for WP template

Tags: html, css, wordpress

I have problem with my template for Wordpress. I have template GeneratePres, and I want replace padding, which is default 40px. But problem is with inline css, which is hard pasted in head style tag. I´ve edit it on FTP at place, which is marked in that css link, but it don´t changed. External plugins does not work. For check that code visit http://znk.cz
Thanks for help

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add this to your stylesheet:

```
.inside-header {padding: 20px !important}
```

Change "20px" to whatever size you would like.